# Proof verification : Union of two countable sets is countable

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, alternative-proof

**Sincere request, don't forget to address my doubt at the end of the proof**

**I have assumed my sets to be disjoint at first but I have also addressed the general scenario as the proof progresses.**

> Set $A$ is said to be countable if there exists a bijection from $A$
>   to $\mathbb{N}$. Every countable set is infinite

To show that : Union of two countable sets is countable

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are countable.
Assume at first that $A\cap B=\phi$

$A $ countable $\Rightarrow \exists f:A\to \mathbb{N} $ a bijection.

$B $ countable $\Rightarrow \exists g:B\to \mathbb{N} $ a bijection.

define. $h:A\cup B \to N$ as

$x\mapsto 2f(x) \; $ if $x\in A$

$x\mapsto 2g(x)+1$ if $x\in B$

Because $A\cup B$ is infinite, it is sufficient to show that $h$ is injective in order to show that $A\cup B$ is countable.

if $x=y$, where $x,y\in A\cup B$, since $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, so,  either both $x$ and $y$ belong to $A$ or both belong to $B$, and because $f$ and $g$ are well defined, so is $h$

Now let $h(x)=h(y)$ where $x,y \in A\cup B$

again, $x$ and $y$ can both belong to $A$ or can both belong to $B$. Hence injectivity of $h$ on $A\cup B$ follows directly from the injectivity of $f$ and $g$ on $A$ and $B$ respectively

Hence, $A\cup B$ is countable.

Now, let $A$ and $B$ be arbitrary countable sets,

then by above method, $A\cup B = [A\setminus (A\cap B)]\cup[A\cap B]\cup [B\setminus (A\cap B)]$ is countable.

**Doubt : Is it safe to assume $A\cap B = \phi$ in the beginning of the proof? I am doubtful here because $A$ and $B$ are countable. Please address  this problem first**

Comment: title says product but body says union !?

Comment: I am sorry, edited

Comment: If you are breaking into cases you do Case 1:  $A$ and $B$ can do what ever you darned well want and Case 2: $A$ and $B$ *don't* do the stuff.  So there is nothing wrong with saying Case 1: $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.  Case 2: they are not disjoint.

Comment: But how do you know $A\setminus (A\cap B), B \setminus (A\cap B)$ and $A \cap B$ are countable?  And you defined countably *infinite*.  What if some of these are finite?

Comment: It  is customary that "countable" means "finite or countably infinite" so that "uncountable" and "not countable" both mean "uncountably infinite".

Comment: I have defined what definition of countable I am using. I have finite sets. Then I have countable sets(which are always infinite) and then I have uncountable sets(that are not finite and not countable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is just about fine.  It's perfectly acceptable to start with the case $A \cap B = \emptyset$ as long as you later address the possibility that $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$, which you do.

The one quibble is that you only proved that the union of *two* disjoint countable sets is countable, yet the end of your proof requires you to use this result for the union of *three* disjoint countable sets.  (I assume you've already separately proved that any subset of a countable set is countable, which is how you know that each of your three components really is countable.)  It's a tiny step, but for completeness you probably should show why the result for a union of three (or any finite) number of disjoint sets follows immediately from the result for a union of two disjoint sets.

**Edited to add:**  Tuvasbien is correct to note that the final step of your proof can be simplified.  $A \cup B = A \cup (B \setminus A)$, and $A \cap (B \setminus A) = \emptyset$.